# Incorrect arXiv BibTeX citation

Tags: arxiv

Upon displaying a new submission, arXiv automatically produces a BibTeX record. This (and other parts of the arXiv's) record is used by authors to cite the submitted preprint, and scraped by the bots of various aggregators (e.g. Google Scholar, ResearchGate, Scopus Preprints, etc.).

Because of the way in which arXiv stores information, such BibTeX records happen to contain serious mistakes (preventing for instance the correct identification of authors, also within arXiv itself) and such mistakes propagate without fail to the other aggregators and eventually make it into the literature.

Is there a way to either

- fix the BibTeX record after an arXiv submission has appeared, or
- provide the arXiv with a correct BibTeX record for a *new* submission, in such a way to avoid mistakes in the automatically generated one?

**Note:** arXiv support is unresponsive/unhelpful about this issue.

**Edit:** The problem is a matter of authors' names formatting.
In particular, arXiv treats names of the form FirstName LastName LastName as FirstName MiddleName LastName. This has been a known issue for many years, but no visible steps were taken by arXiv to fix the problem.
According to arXiv's [help page for the "author" field](https://info.arxiv.org/help/prep.html#author), names of the form FirstName LastName LastName ought to be entered as they are. The example provided there is *John von Neumann*. Note that the BibTeX record of this name is correct, as its author field reads
`author={John von Neumann}`
and it is thus abbreviated as *Neumann, J. v.* and listed under N in the alphabetical order (since it is so, by convention, in German).

This problem however is language-dependent: on the arXiv the Dutch/Belgian *van* follows the same pattern as *von*, but in Belgian it is correct to list the name under V, so a BibTeX record of the form `author={Eric Van Rompuy}` (example from Wikipedia) would be incorrect (the correct one being `author={Van Rompuy, Eric}`).

Unfortunately, the German *von* is the tip of the iceberg.

The BibTeX record is in fact only an instance of much larger issue. Indeed, suppose to look up a name of the form FirstName LastName1 LastName2 with the arXiv search field. When you find the author you are interested in, you click on the link on the author name in the first relevant publication in the results. In this case, arXiv occasionally redirects you to the search results for LastName2, FN. LN1. which is usually totally uninformative.
Whether or not the author has an [arXiv author identifier](https://info.arxiv.org/help/author_identifiers.html) or its identifier is linked to Orcid, it does not matter at all.

Comment: "Because of the way in which arXiv stores information, such BibTeX records happen to contain serious mistakes" -- can you point out examples and/or be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Yes, this is a matter of arXiv formatting metadata incorrectly.

Comment: It sounds like the only long-term solution is to persuade arXiv to fix their system. I wonder if anyone on this site works for arXiv or a similar organization and could give advice.